# Problem with shinny app Markdown Latex kable function

Tags: r, shiny, latex, r-markdown, kable

I am building a shinny app in R with the aim to submit files and make a final report.

The report is made with a markdown file. In this .Rmd file I am using the kable() function to make tables.  My code in the mardown file is:

```
library(kableExtra)

data<-params$n
kable(data, "latex", booktabs=T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped", full_width = T)

# table(n)
```

My main problem is when I am running the app and I change the input file and then try to download the new file, the app reports a server problem and the message in console is:

```
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'file23b036421a70.aux'
   Non-existent destination files:
      'file23b036421a70.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "/tmp/RtmpHgVSDf/file23b036421a70.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'file23b036421a70.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
! Undefined control sequence.
l.89 \rowcolors
               {2}{gray!6}{white} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11990 strings out of 493029
 171648 string characters out of 6136233
 271987 words of memory out of 5000000
 15417 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 16571 words of font info for 21 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 31i,3n,35p,257b,299s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Warning: Error in : Failed to compile /tmp/RtmpHgVSDf/file23b036421a70.tex. See /tmp/RtmpHgVSDf/file23b036421a70.log for more info.
  [No stack trace available]
```

Can any one guide me in whats happened?